# Want to find duplicates in list which have overlaps timespans

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
public class  MyRows
{
    public string StartStop { get; set; }
    public string EndStop { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Day { get; set; }
}
```

```
List<MyRows> lmr = new List<MyRows>();
lmr.Add(new MyRows { StartStop = "a", EndStop = "b", StartTime = new TimeSpan(09, 00, 00), EndTime = new TimeSpan(11, 00, 00),Day=DayOfWeek.Sunday.ToString() });
lmr.Add(new MyRows { StartStop = "a", EndStop = "b", StartTime = new TimeSpan(09, 00, 00), EndTime = new TimeSpan(11, 00, 00), Day = DayOfWeek.Sunday.ToString() });
lmr.Add(new MyRows { StartStop = "a", EndStop = "b", StartTime = new TimeSpan(10, 00, 00), EndTime = new TimeSpan(12, 00, 00), Day = DayOfWeek.Tuesday.ToString() });
lmr.Add(new MyRows { StartStop = "a", EndStop = "b", StartTime = new TimeSpan(10, 30, 00), EndTime = new TimeSpan(12, 00, 00), Day = DayOfWeek.Sunday.ToString() });
lmr.Add(new MyRows { StartStop = "a", EndStop = "b", StartTime = new TimeSpan(09, 00, 00), EndTime = new TimeSpan(13, 00, 00), Day = DayOfWeek.Tuesday.ToString() });
lmr.Add(new MyRows { StartStop = "a", EndStop = "b", StartTime = new TimeSpan(09, 00, 00), EndTime = new TimeSpan(11, 00, 00), Day = DayOfWeek.Thursday.ToString() });
lmr.Add(new MyRows { StartStop = "a", EndStop = "b", StartTime = new TimeSpan(11, 00, 00), EndTime = new TimeSpan(12, 00, 00), Day = DayOfWeek.Thursday.ToString() });
```

I want to find duplicates on the basis of StartStop, EndStop, StartTime, EndTime (same TimeSpans) and DayOfWeek

For example, in above list"

- first object is duplicate with second and forth object (forth bcoz
  timespan overlapping)
- third object is duplicated with fifth object because of timespan overlapping.
- sixth object is not duplicated with seventh beacuse timespan are not overlapping but day is same.

Comment: One way to achieve this by using Linq, recursively

Comment: I am beginner in Linq. 
I have created one method to check overlapping time spans and that method returns timespans are same,overlapping and notoverlapping.
using this method i am iterating list but it fails in some scenario.

Comment: Then post you method but it would be better if the method returned bool.  And why do you name the class a plural?

Comment: Ohh..sorry it must have "MyRow".. My mistake. I want to show those dupicated rows on UI thats why return type should not of bool type.

Comment: Then clarify the question because Duplicate is boolean.  And post the method.   If StartStop and EndStop are not part of the problem then eliminate that from the question.

Comment: Sir, The question self describes that list of duplicated rows in the above list.
There are rules
**1.** StartStop and EndStop Should be same.
**2.** check StartTime and EndTime are same within list having same Stops then check days if days are repeated then those rows are duplicated.
**3.** If times are overlapp within list then check days if days are repeated then those rows are duplicated.
**4.** If times are not overlapping then those rows are not duplicated.

Comment: In the answer you accept the method returns bool.

Comment: `List<MyRow> result = lmr.Where(i => lmr.Any(o => YourCondition(i, o) && i != o)).ToList<MyRow>();`

Returns list of records which are duplicated.

Comment: private bool YourCondition is the method call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go without complication,

```
   var result = lmr.Where(i => lmr.Any(o => YourCondition(i,o) && i != o));

    //up to you
    private bool YourCondition(MyRow i, MyRow o)
    {
        return i.StartTime >= o.StartTime && i.EndTime <= o.EndTime && i.Day == o.Day;
    }
```

Comment: seems correct :)
Thank you Dipak... 
Linq always reduces the complexities.

Comment: Thanks, I think "Linq sometimes reduces the complexities"