# Find all the common time from List of time provided by each user

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I had asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826123/find-common-datetime-from-list-of-datetime-if-no-common-then-find-most-common) question previously. The idea is same except that I have to find all the common time within certain `TimeSpan`.

**Background**

Lets suppose,

I want to meet some peoples, and I say I want to meet certain peoples between Datetime X(2014-02-16 09:00:00.000) to DateTime Y(2014-02-26 05:00:00.000). And I say I want to the meeting to last for at least `N` number of hours.

Then the peoples i want to meet with will reply saying i will be available in following dates:

```
Date1(Certain date from certain start time to certain end time), 

Date2(certain date from certain time to certain time),

...
```

and so on.

**Objective**

I then have to find if there exists a time range that includes in all the user's response.

Lets consider these are the responses

> `Attendee1`(Some GuidId):
>
> Response1: Start Time=2014-02-23 09:00 AM, EndTime = 2014-02-23 11:00
>   AM,
>
> Response2 : Start Time=2014-02-24 10:00 AM, EndTime = 2014-02-24 12:00
>   PM,
>
> Response3 : Start Time=2014-02-25 10:00 AM, EndTime = 2014-02-25 11:00
>   AM,
>
> Response4 : Start Time=2014-02-23 01:00 PM, EndTime = 2014-02-17 5:00
>   PM
>
> `Attendee2`(Some GuidId):
>
> Response1: Start Time=2014-02-22 09:00 AM, EndTime = 2014-02-22 05:00
>   PM,
>
> Response2 : Start Time=2014-02-23 09:00 AM, EndTime = 2014-02-23 05:00
>   PM,
>
> Response3 : Start Time=2014-02-25 09:00 AM, EndTime = 2014-02-25 12:00
>   PM,
>
> `Attendee3`(Some GuidId):
>
> Response1: Start Time=2014-02-22 11:00 AM, EndTime = 2014-02-22 02:00
>   PM,
>
> Response2 : Start Time=2014-02-23 04:00 PM, EndTime = 2014-02-23 03:00
>   PM,
>
> Response3 : Start Time=2014-02-23 4:30 PM, EndTime = 2014-02-23 05:30
>   PM,
>
> Response4 : Start Time=2014-02-24 02:00 AM, EndTime = 2014-02-24 05:00
>   PM,
>
> Response5 : Start Time=2014-02-25 11:00 AM, EndTime = 2014-02-25 12:00
>   PM,

So, if possible, I should come up with something that will say here are the matches found, if not then just find if the common time exists for all the user's or not.

`Time X to Time Y` (Difference between X and Y should be at least the TimeSpan mentioned) : `Number of Attendee in this match = N`(type = int, 1 or 2 or as many match as found)

```
Time A to Time B : Number of Attendee in this match = N
```

...

etc.

**PS:**

It is a MVC 5.1 application and database is created using code first approach.
So in database there is table called Appointment which stores the StartDateTime and EndDateTime

Here are my `DataModels`

```
public class Appointment
{

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }    
    public TimeSpan MinAppointmentDuration { get; set; }  

}
```

and between these dates people(Attendee) attending will give their response. Each person(who will respond), their information is stored in database table called Attendees

```
public class Attendee
{
    public Guid AttendeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses { get; set; } 
}
```

And for each user their response is stored in Responses table whose model would look like

```
public class Response
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid AttendeeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }

}
```

This is what I have done but it doesn't work.

```
public class CommonTime
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan MinAppointmenttime { get; set; }
    public int NumAttendees 
    { 
        get { return Responses.Select(x => x.AttendeeId).Distinct().Count(); } 
    }
    public List<DataModels.Response> Responses { get; set; }

    public CommonTime(DataModels.Response response, TimeSpan time)
    {
        Responses = new List<DataModels.Response>();
        Start = response.StartDateTime;
        End = response.EndDateTime;
        MinAppointmenttime = time;
    }

    public void MergeCommonTime(DataModels.Response response)
    {
        if(Start <= response.StartDateTime && response.EndDateTime<=End)
        {
            Start = response.StartDateTime;
            End = response.EndDateTime;
            if((End-Start)>=MinAppointmenttime)
            {
                Responses.Add(response);
            }

        }
    }

    public List<CommonTime> FindCommonMatches(Guid appointmentId)
    {
        var appointment = _db.Appointments.Find(appointmentId);
        var attendees = appointment.Attendees.ToList();
        var matches = new List<CommonTime>();
        bool isFirstAttendee = true;
        foreach (var attendee in attendees)
        {
            if (isFirstAttendee)
            {
                foreach (var response in attendee.Responses)
                {
                    matches.Add(new CommonTime(response, appointment.MinAppointmentDuration));

                }
                isFirstAttendee = false;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var response in attendee.Responses)
                {
                    matches.ForEach(x => x.MergeCommonTime(response));
                }
            }
        }

        return matches;
    }

}
```

So in this case if `Attendee X`(with some Guid Id) gives his/her availability as
[image]

and `Attendee Y` gives his/her availibility as

[image]

this is the common match I get

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Which is not what I want as I explained.

So, what should I do to get what I want.

---

### Edit:

Based upon Answer from **Zache**

```
    public class Meeting
    {
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }

        public List<DataModels.Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }

    }

    public class Requirement
    {
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }

        public TimeSpan MinHours { get; set; }

        public int MinAttendees { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Meeting> Meetings()
        {
            var possibleMeetings = new List<Meeting>();
            var availableHours = (End - Start).TotalHours;

            for (var i = 0; i < availableHours - MinHours.Hours; i++)
                yield return new Meeting
                {
                    Start = Start.AddHours(i),
                    End = Start.AddHours(i+MinHours.Hours)
                };
        }
    }

    public class Scheduler
    {
        public IEnumerable<Meeting> Schedule(Requirement req, List<DataModels.Attendee> attendees)
        {
            var fullMatches = new List<Meeting>();
            var partialMatches = new List<Meeting>();

            foreach (var m in req.Meetings())
            {
                foreach (var a in attendees)
                {
                    if (fullMatches.Any())
                    {
                        if (a.Responses.Any(r => r.StartDateTime <= m.Start && r.EndDateTime >= m.End))
                        {
                            if (m.Attendees == null)
                            {
                                m.Attendees = new List<DataModels.Attendee> { a };
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                m.Attendees.Add(a);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break; // If we found one full match we aren't interested in the partials anymore.
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (a.Responses.Any(r => r.StartDateTime <= m.Start && r.EndDateTime >= m.End))
                        {
                            if (m.Attendees == null)
                            {
                                m.Attendees = new List<DataModels.Attendee> { a };
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                m.Attendees.Add(a);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (m.Attendees != null)
                {
                    if (m.Attendees.Count == attendees.Count)
                        fullMatches.Add(m);
                    else if (m.Attendees.Count >= req.MinAttendees)
                        partialMatches.Add(m);
                }
            }

            return fullMatches.Any() ? fullMatches : partialMatches;
        }
    }
}
```

in **repository**

```
public IEnumerable<Meeting> FindCommonMatches(Guid appointmentId)
{
    var appointment = _db.Appointments.Find(appointmentId);
    var attendees = appointment.Attendees.Where(a => a.HasResponded == true).ToList();
    var req = new Requirement
    {
        Start = appointment.StartDateTime,
        End = appointment.EndDateTime,
        MinHours = appointment.MinAppointmentDuration,
        MinAttendees = 1
    };
    var schedule = new Scheduler();
    var schedules = schedule.Schedule(req, attendees);
    return schedules;
 }
```

**StartDate**: `2/24/2014 11:30:00 AM`//that I set while creating appointment

**EndDate**: `2/25/2014 11:30:00 AM`

When the first user responds with following data:

[image]

matches result:

[image]

[image]

when second attendee responds with following data

[image]

matches result

[image]

[image]

Here the common matches should have been:

```
Match1: 2/24/2014 10:00:00 AM   to   2/24/2014 11:00:00 AM
 Match2: 2/25/2014 9:00:00 AM   to   2/25/2014 11:00:00 AM
```

Comment: How in the world, the End Times in the Attendee responses are earlier than the Start Time, or am I missing something ? And they all seem to be 17th Feb 2014.

Comment: thats something i made up, you can see the image for proper response, i 've edited it, I have done validation on the server side for endtimes to be greater than starttime

Comment: So what you're looking for is overlapping time ranges? Sounds similar to finding overlapping intervals. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542892/possible-interview-question-how-to-find-all-overlapping-intervals, for example. Just replace integers with date/time values.

Comment: @JimMischel I want to find all the matches that exists between each attendee and come up with a list that shows all the mathes with number of people in a particular match

Comment: @JimMischel the link you gave is to find if there exists a common interval. I want to find common time, its something different

Comment: @Biplov13: If you can find an overlapping interval in which all attendees are available, then by definition any point within that interval is a common time.

Comment: Your second availability interval of attendee x looks wrong  - from 5:30 PM to 6:30 AM of same day

Comment: To the people, Who are thinking of Bounty, I spent 4 hours with different solution...Its not leading anywhere... deleted all answers myself..

Comment: @Dipak Its really annoying me as well. Did not think it would be this difficult, you can check the answer given and result to that answer in my question edit, may be that can give some hint. I've been trying as well but it leads no where. From what I have in mind is to find common date first then find the time in that particular date.

Comment: If you aren't going to put in any effort then this is the wrong place for you.

Comment: @Zache I am trying to put effort. I wanted to ask something regarding your answer. You didn't reply and now you deleted your answer. If you still had the answer and answered some of my questions I had regarding your answer may be we could have solved it. Anyways thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following `GetMeetingWindows` function will return a list of all matching windows and available attendees.  Full or minimum attendee stipulations can then be applied as required on the result e.g.

```
GetMeetingWindows(attendees, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)).Where(x => x.AvailableAttendees.Count() == attendees.Count());
```

I have assumed the supplied attendee responses have already taken into consideration the overall time frame available for the meeting, but if this is not the case then this restriction can be added as an additional attendee which is then filtered for in the result, e.g.

```
GetMeetingWindows(...).Where(x => x.AvailableAttendees.Contains(meetingRoom));
```

The code:

```
public class Attendee
{
    public ICollection<Response> Responses { get; set; } 
}

public class Response
{
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class Window
{
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Attendee> AvailableAttendees { get; set; }   
}

public IEnumerable<Window> GetMeetingWindows(IEnumerable<Attendee> attendees, TimeSpan meetingDuration)
{
    var windows = new List<Window>();
    var responses = attendees.SelectMany(x => x.Responses).Where(x => x.EndDateTime - x.StartDateTime >= meetingDuration);

    foreach(var time in (responses.Select(x => x.StartDateTime)).Distinct())
    {
        var matches = attendees.Select(x => new { 
            Attendee = x, 
            MatchingAvailabilities = x.Responses.Where(y => y.StartDateTime <= time && y.EndDateTime >= time.Add(meetingDuration)) 
        });

        windows.Add(new Window { 
            StartDateTime = time, 
            EndDateTime = matches.SelectMany(x => x.MatchingAvailabilities).Min(x => x.EndDateTime), 
            AvailableAttendees = matches.Where(y => y.MatchingAvailabilities.Any()).Select(x => x.Attendee) 
        });
    }

    foreach(var time in (responses.Select(x => x.EndDateTime)).Distinct())
    {
        var matches = attendees.Select(x => new { 
            Attendee = x, 
            MatchingAvailabilities = x.Responses.Where(y => y.EndDateTime >= time && y.StartDateTime <= time.Add(-meetingDuration)) 
        });

        windows.Add(new Window { 
            EndDateTime = time, 
            StartDateTime = matches.SelectMany(x => x.MatchingAvailabilities).Max(x => x.StartDateTime), 
            AvailableAttendees = matches.Where(y => y.MatchingAvailabilities.Any()).Select(x => x.Attendee) 
        });
    }

    return windows.GroupBy(x => new { x.StartDateTime, x.EndDateTime }).Select(x => x.First()).OrderBy(x => x.StartDateTime).ThenBy(x => x.EndDateTime);
}

public void Test() 
{
    var attendees = new List<Attendee>();
    attendees.Add(new Attendee { Responses = new[] { 
        new Response { StartDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-24 9:00:00 AM"), EndDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-24 11:00:00 AM") },
        new Response { StartDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-24 2:00:00 PM"), EndDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-24 4:00:00 PM") },
        new Response { StartDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-25 9:00:00 AM"), EndDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-25 11:00:00 AM") },
        new Response { StartDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-25 3:00:00 PM"), EndDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-25 5:00:00 PM") }
    }});
    attendees.Add(new Attendee { Responses = new[] { 
        new Response { StartDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-24 10:00:00 AM"), EndDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-24 11:00:00 AM") },
        new Response { StartDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-24 4:00:00 PM"), EndDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-24 5:00:00 PM") },
        new Response { StartDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-25 9:00:00 AM"), EndDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-25 11:00:00 AM") }
    }});

    var windows = GetMeetingWindows(attendees, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60));
    foreach(var window in windows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Start: {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}, End: {1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}, AttendeeCount: {2}", window.StartDateTime, window.EndDateTime, window.AvailableAttendees.Count()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats brilliant!!! Works perfectly. Could you explain the part where you do var `matches = attendees.Select(x => new { 
            Attendee = x, 
            MatchingAvailabilities = x.Responses.Where(y => y.StartDateTime <= time && y.EndDateTime >= time.Add(meetingDuration)) 
        });` I always thought when you do `Select` and then `x=> new {..}` you also have to mention the class. But could you explain how are these `Attendee` and `MatchingAvailabilities` are being generated?

Comment: That's an Anonymous Type (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), a nameless disposable collection of properties, and very useful for holding temporary results in multi step LINQ queries. You can assign each property any name of your choosing on-the-fly, or omit the name altogether if selecting a property which already has a name, e.g.: 
`var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => new { MyNumber = x });`
`var squares = numbers.Select(x => new { x.MyNumber, MySquare = x.MyNumber * x.MyNumber });`